# Get an RSS feed for a YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube, rss, feeds, youtube-playlist

Since a few weeks ago, it looks like YouTube has disabled RSS feeds for playlists. Is there another way to get an RSS feed for a YouTube playlist?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's because v2 API was deprecated at that time.

To get the updated feed url use this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=YOURPLAYLISTIDHERE
```

Comment: why RSS validators like https://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/ say this feed does not validate? Does it mean an RSS feed reader will not be able to work with it?

Comment: Seems to contain just a few videos from the beginning of the playlist, not the recent ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this often, this is a bookmarklet for extracting the RSS feed:

```
javascript:location='https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=%27+(window.location.href).split(%27list=%27)[1]
```

To use the bookmarklet, create a bookmark and post the above script where you'd normally have your url. Then navigate to a youtube playlist page and click the bookmark. It will extract the playlist id and automatically redirect you to the rss feed.